# 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'profile'. - accessing to views by anonymous and authenticateds users

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, httpresponse

I have the following User schema:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, null=True)
    username = models.CharField(_('username'), max_length=30, null=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=30, blank=True)

    objects = UserManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"

    def __str__(self):
        return "@{}".format(self.email)
```

And I have the `UserProfile` class

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='profile'
    )
```

According to previous models, one user have one userprofile. All right.

I have some views that it is interesting that they can be accessed by both anonymous users and logged in users.

When an logged in user access to view, this ask the profile data information and show them in the template

When an anonymous user access to view, this should render the template, obviously without profile data information.

This view is named `article_detail` and their small logic is the following:

```
def article_detail(request, slug):
    user = request.user

    # I ask fot the profile user 
    profile = user.profile

    queryset = Article.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now())
    article = get_object_or_404(Article, slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'blog/article_detail.html',
                    {'article': article,'userprofile':profile })
```

When an authenticated user access to this view, the data profile information is renderized, validating the `profile = user.profile` section code. This is O.K.

But when an anonymous user access to this view I get the message:

```
'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'profile'
```

I trying use the `is_authenticated()` function when an user perform a request:

```
def article_detail(request, slug):
    user = request.user
    if user.is_authenticated():
        profile = user.profile
        queryset = Article.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now())
        article = get_object_or_404(Article, slug=slug)

        context = {'article': article, 'userprofile':profile }
        return render(request, context,
                        'blog/article_detail.html')
```

But when I access to view when an user is not authenticated I get this message:

```
The view blog.views.article_detail didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead
```

When I access to view when an user is authenticated I get this message:

```
raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: {'comments': <QuerySet []>, 'article': <Article: Los gatos callejeros>, 'userprofile': <UserProfile: @botibagl@gmail.com>}
[12/Aug/2017 00:01:07] "GET /article/los-gatos-callejeros/ HTTP/1.1" 500 105628
```

Is possible that my problem to be of identation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view does not work for authenticated users, because in this line:

```
        return render(request, context,
                        'blog/article_detail.html')
```

you switched template name with `context` - it should be:

```
        return render(request, 'blog/article_detail.html', context)
```

For the view to work with anonymous users, it has to return a HttpResponse, your version returns `None`. You could rewrite your view like this:

```
def article_detail(request, slug):
    user = request.user
    article = get_object_or_404(Article, slug=slug)
    context = {'article': article}
    if user.is_authenticated():
        context['profile'] = user.profile
    return render(request, 'blog/article_detail.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

thee only reason why u get user as anonomus user is that u are not logged in or user is not authenticated, so please login to ur account the moment you open the app..and the issue is resolved